# Set textarea's caret position using x and y position

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I want to implement inline edition, so if user clicks on a div with some text, the textarea will appear at the same position as clicked div's position and will get the text from the div. This is fine for me, but what I want to do next is to set textarea's caret position according to x and y position from div click event. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="content" style="display: block; z-index: 10">Some text</div>

<textarea id="editor" style="position: absolute; display: none; z-index: 11"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$('#content').click(function(e) {
    var content = $(this);
    var editor = $('#editor');

    var position = content.offset();

    editor.css('left', position.left);
    editor.css('top', position.top);
    editor.val(content.text());
    editor.show();

    var mousePosition = { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY };

    // here I want to set the #editor caret position at the same place,
    // where user clicks the #content (mousePosition variable)
});
```

Comment: The caret is always positioned at a text node, you can't position it to an empty area.

Comment: The area won't be empty - it will have the same content as the div.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: I think that contenteditable feture will cause problems, when you use some binding tools like Knockout or angular. If you look at some popular task management tools like wunderlist.com or asana.com they don't use contenteditable.

Comment: Why these minuses? Something wrong with the question?

Comment: @Teemu, I've added some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you could do something like this:

```
createTextArea = function (e) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
        start = range.startOffset,
        target = e.target,
        setPoint;
    while (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'div') {
        target = target.parentElement;
        if (!target) return;
    }
    range.setStart(target, 0);
    setPoint = range.toString().length;
    // place and show #editor
    editor.focus();
    editor.setSelectionRange(setPoint, setPoint);
    return;
};
```

[An example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BY5NL/). Notice that this works only in modern browsers. Older IE's don't have Input API, and the Selection/Range model is totally different.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have found a solution at the same moment :)

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Saved me a lot of time. I also create a slightly change version of your example allowing to mark a range of text in case it's in the same element. see http://jsfiddle.net/BY5NL/3/

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

JS:

```
function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
    var caretPos = 0, containerEl = null, sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
                caretPos = range.endOffset;
            }
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
            var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
            editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
            var tempRange = range.duplicate();
            tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
            tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
            caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
        }
    }
    return caretPos;
}

$.fn.selectRange = function (start, end) {
    if (!end) end = start;
    return this.each(function () {
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
$('#content').click(function (e) {
    var content = $(this);
    var editor = $('#editor');

    var caret = getCaretPosition(this);

    var position = content.offset();

    editor.css('left', position.left);
    editor.css('top', position.top);
    editor.val(content.text());
    editor.show();

    var mousePosition = { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY };

    // here I want to set the #editor caret position at the same place,
    // where user clicks the #content (mousePosition variable)

    editor.selectRange(caret, caret);
});
```